# Loki that is set up as Prometheus datasource in order to have alerts on log counts, is wrongly configured, getting 404 error

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, grafana-loki, kube-prometheus-stack

We have added Loki twice as additional datasource for grafana in `kube-prometheus-stack` helm chart, the first is as type `loki`, the second one as type `prometheus` as the second is an only hack that allows grafana to have alerts from loki:

```
grafana:
  ## Configure additional grafana datasources (passed through tpl)
  ## ref: http://docs.grafana.org/administration/provisioning/#datasources
  additionalDataSources:
    - name: Loki
      type: loki
      access: proxy
      url: http://loki.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:3100
      jsonData:
        maxLines: 1000
    - name: LokiAsPrometheus
      type: prometheus
      access: proxy
      url: http://loki.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:3100
      jsonData:
        maxLines: 1000
```

But when I create a new dashboard and select `LokiAsPromtheus` as datasorce, grafana http responses respond with errors, like there is some misconfiguration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was critical to put `/loki` resource as the part of loki-as-prometheus url like that:

```
grafana:
  ## Configure additional grafana datasources (passed through tpl)
  ## ref: http://docs.grafana.org/administration/provisioning/#datasources
  additionalDataSources:
    - name: Loki
      type: loki
      access: proxy
      url: http://loki.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:3100
      jsonData:
        maxLines: 1000
    - name: LokiAsPrometheus
      type: prometheus
      access: proxy
      url: http://loki.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:3100/loki
      jsonData:
        maxLines: 1000
```