# configure loki as prometheus data source not working

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-operator, grafana-loki

I wanted to create an alert if there is an error in the logs.
I have added Loki as a Prometheus data source in Grafana. Appended Loki to the end of your URL, like this: http://ipaddress:3100/loki with basic auth and selected the Prometheus data source type but while adding the data source it throws 500 error and when I checked logs its says unknown error(500). I'm not sure what's going wrong here. To make sure Loki works fine, I have added the URL(http://ipaddress:3100) in Loki data source with basic auth and checked whether it's working or not. As expected it's worked. But not sure why it's not working when Loki was added as a Prometheus data source. Does anybody know what caused this error?.

Note: i'm using cloud prometheus operator instance

Comment: Is it possible to add Loki as a Prometheus data source? I never had heart about that.

Comment: yes its possible. please find more info here https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/1222

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794873/loki-that-is-set-up-as-prometheus-datasource-in-order-to-have-alerts-on-log-coun

Answer (score 1):

It was critical to put /loki resource as the part of loki-as-prometheus url like that:

```
grafana:
  ## Configure additional grafana datasources (passed through tpl)
  ## ref: http://docs.grafana.org/administration/provisioning/#datasources
  additionalDataSources:
    - name: Loki
      type: loki
      access: proxy
      url: http://loki.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:3100
      jsonData:
        maxLines: 1000
    - name: LokiAsPrometheus
      type: prometheus
      access: proxy
      url: http://loki.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:3100/loki
      jsonData:
        maxLines: 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you unable to use a loki alert rule for setting up that alert?

https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/rules/